# How to define properties of an object returned by a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jsdoc

I'm working on Gscript.

```
function globales() {
  var data = {
    dir: DriveApp.getFolderById('id'),
    sinky: "test",
    numberino : 42
  };
  return data;
}


function test()
{
  var rep = globales().dir.getName() // get the name of the directory.
  return rep
}
```

I would like to use jsdoc so that when I write this code, the return type of the variable "dir" can display 'DriveApp.Folder'.
Basically, specify for all keys within the 'data' structure in 'global' function : the type of the data (e.g., a string, a number, a DriveApp.Folder)

Something like `@param {string}` to precise function parameter type.

Comment: what 's the question?

Comment: @liquidkat trou de balle

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for the [`@property`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-property.html) tag. Based on your code you can try something like the following:

```
/**
*Returns an Object with some global variables
*
*@function globales
*@property {DriveApp.Folder} dir - Folder ID
*@property {String} sinky - Some string
*@property {int} numberino - Some number
*@returns {Object} - Array with different data
*
*/

function globales() {
  var data = {
    dir: DriveApp.getFolderById('id'),
    sinky: "test",
    numberino : 42
  };
  return data;
}


function test()
{
  var rep = globales().dir.getName() // get the name of the directory.
  return rep
}
```

And the output in the documentation would be:

[image]

May vary depending on how you want to format it but this should work. If your function has input parameters you can use the `@param` tag and it will add a separate table.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer, i was a little bit lost about the way I must use JSdoc.

I just tested your code on Google Apps Script interface but it doesn't recognize type of return of the function 'globales' (return type : any). 

I've seen something like a declaration of a class (here the class Data for 'data' struct., this class should have properties matching with values type in the 'data' struc). 

But It doesn't work, I think I'm missunderstanding something

Comment: Hi, my bad, I thought you were trying to use JSDoc natively. My example works by running JSDoc in the command line as [explained in their docs.](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html). As for running JSDoc within Apps Script, [this feature request on Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156230902) suggests that it is not possible at the moment. Keep in mind that JSDoc is for documentation purposes. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but are you actually trying to do something that affects the code?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your help, in fact, I just want people looking at my code to know what type of variable I'm using.It is also useful for me because when I call some variables, I find it more convenient because I can see the proposed methods for the type of a variable.

Comment: I see. You could learn the [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) notation to be able to generate the documentation files if you need them, and people will be familiar with it. You can also improvise a comment format yourself, but as far as Apps Script goes it doesn't have any built-in features to recognize this. It's up to you to document it properly.